# iOS How to check how many request was sent for server, parse swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have something strange with my parse server, I start to check Analytics toll at the parse, and I saw during some period I have more than**600 request per minutes**, to the server, in my opinion, is not possible because only I am, testing app.

[image]

At image you can see a trend, I have 10-14 requests, and immediately I get 600?
How I can check how many requests are sent my app?

Comment: doing metrics of the metrics seems like a _metriception_, but who does the metrics of the metrics of the metrics...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a proxy to catch your request

-> [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) is a really useful tool for this

If you want count in your app how many are sent, it depends on how you organised your code.

-> you could create a counter for this (in your custom "ReqeustMaker" create a static variable or even in in a shared instance class if you need more fancy stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code you can trap all the calls, and find them all on Xcode debug console:

```
class MyURLProtocol: NSURLProtocol {
    class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        print("Requests : \(request.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
        return false
    }
}
```

and call this when app is loading:

```
URLProtocol.registerClass(MyURLProtocol.self)
```